# Error while trying to dockerize a Grails application

Tags: docker, grails, dockerfile

I'm trying to dockerize this Grails application (https://github.com/continuumsecurity/RopeyTasks) using this docker image (https://hub.docker.com/r/mozart/grails/) and the following Dockerfile :

```
FROM mozart/grails:2
MAINTAINER Manuel Ortiz Bey <ortiz.manuel@mozartanalytics.com>

# Copy App files
COPY . /app

# Run Grails refresh-dependencies command to 
# pre-download dependencies but not create
# unnecessary build files or artifacts.
RUN grails refresh-dependencies

# Set Default Behavior
ENTRYPOINT ["grails"]
CMD ["run-app"]
```

But when I run the command `docker run -it -p 8080:8080 test/grails-app` I got the following error message :

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  170.4MB
Step 1/6 : FROM mozart/grails:2
 ---> a656bf34ad8e
Step 2/6 : MAINTAINER Manuel Ortiz Bey <ortiz.manuel@mozartanalytics.com>
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 194a5f4e84e3
Step 3/6 : COPY . /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 618a47fd4d06
Step 4/6 : RUN grails refresh-dependencies
 ---> Running in 74b1b5cd7587
| Loading Grails 2.5.3
| Configuring classpath
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.5, cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2.2, org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:jar:1.0.2-grails-2.4, org.grails.plugins:standalone:zip:9.0.0.M4, org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:zip:2.1.2, org.grails.plugins:cache:zip:1.1.8, org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:zip:1.9.9, org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:zip:4.3.6.1, org.grails.plugins:database-migration:zip:1.4.0, org.grails.plugins:jquery:zip:1.11.1: Could not transfer artifact org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.5 from/to grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): Received fatal alert: protocol_version (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.5, org.grails.plugins:standalone:zip:9.0.0.M4, org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:zip:2.1.2, org.grails.plugins:cache:zip:1.1.8, org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:zip:1.9.9, org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:zip:4.3.6.1, org.grails.plugins:database-migration:zip:1.4.0, org.grails.plugins:jquery:zip:1.11.1: Could not transfer artifact org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.5 from/to grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): Received fatal alert: protocol_version (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:zip:2.1.2, org.grails.plugins:cache:zip:1.1.8, org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:zip:1.9.9: Could not transfer artifact org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:zip:2.1.2 from/to grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): Received fatal alert: protocol_version (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:zip:2.1.2, org.grails.plugins:cache:zip:1.1.8, org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:zip:1.9.9: Could not transfer artifact org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:zip:2.1.2 from/to grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): Received fatal alert: protocol_version
| Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
The command '/bin/sh -c grails refresh-dependencies' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

My docker version is :

```
# docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.06.1-ce
 API version:       1.38
 Go version:        go1.10.3
 Git commit:        e68fc7a
 Built:             Tue Aug 21 17:24:58 2018
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          18.06.1-ce
  API version:      1.38 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.3
  Git commit:       e68fc7a
  Built:            Tue Aug 21 17:23:24 2018
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Do you have some sort of network proxy setup that you need to reach repo.grails.org?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to build the app out in the host and put the runnable in the image?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem! Couldn't found a way arround it but to use the base Dockerfile from the same image mozart/grails and somehow that worked for me.

Here is dockerfile with some minor modifications:

```
FROM java:8

# Set Grails version (min: 3.0.0; max: 3.2.8).
ENV GRAILS_VERSION 2.4.5

# Install Grails
WORKDIR /usr/lib/jvm
RUN wget https://github.com/grails/grails-core/releases/download/v$GRAILS_VERSION/grails-$GRAILS_VERSION.zip && \
unzip grails-$GRAILS_VERSION.zip && \rm -rf grails-$GRAILS_VERSION.zip && \ln -s grails-$GRAILS_VERSION grails

# Setup Grails path.
ENV GRAILS_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/grails
ENV PATH $GRAILS_HOME/bin:$PATH

# Create App Directory
RUN mkdir /app

# Copy App files
COPY . /app

# Set Workdir /app and download dependecies
WORKDIR /app
RUN grails refresh-dependencies

# Make port 8080 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8080

# Set Default Behavior
ENTRYPOINT ["grails"]
CMD ["run-app"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, add this repositories in BuildConfig.groovy

```
mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
mavenRepo 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'
mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"
```